# Need to download the whole video first before playing

Tags: video.js

I need to download the whole video first before playing, is there a method to cache the video or force it to download the whole file?

Using the example given, in chrome it appears to download part of the video and then just stops.  I assume this the HTML5 video player trying to save bandwidth but actually I need to have the whole file downloaded.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting what you'd like to do correctly, then in HTML, set the `preload="auto"` flag within a :`video` tag.

```
<video controls preload="auto">
   <source src="..." type="...">
 </video>
```

Comment: Yes I have that option set.

Further investigation indicates if I play and then pause the video it immediately indicates the video has fully loaded.

I might try doing a quick play / pause to see if that triggers it.

Comment: Turns out Firefox does work as expected - Chrome on the other hand doesnt. The event loadedalldata fires for Firefox.